# Django version selection

Tags: python, django

Greetings,
I am currently working on a long term project that uses Django 1.1.1, and we are planning to release it around march of 2010.

Now while surfing I came upon to this [article](http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/welcome-django-advent/) which says the planned release date of Django 1.2.0 is March 9, 2010.

Now I am a bit confused. If I should continue developing under 1.1.1 or start developing using 1.2.0 beta.

Comment: Based on my experience, the release date of django is most likely to be late. SO just pick the latest stable one.

Comment: And his development schedule could be a bit optimistic. There aren't going to be any changes among the 1.2 betas that will affect the simultaneous development of the project. So why force yourself into an older branch when you will likely need to utilize the features of 1.2? I need ALL of them for my project... better CSRF, email backends, multi-db, messages framework, smart "if", model validation, Model.objects.raw(), and so forth...

Comment: @jonwd7: You need better cross-site request forgery?

Comment: @jcd I was being brief because I'm pretty sure you or anyone who reads it is not a moron (and can figure it out). But thanks for being a smart ass, it's what I like waking up to. If you really want I can take up the ~400 remaining characters of this comment to describe to you, in detail, why exactly I want Django 1.2's improved cross-site request forgery protection.  But instead I'll use it to ask for you to go troll somewhere else, as I see that you haven't left a constructive answer or comment of your own on this entire page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say only develop for the latest version if there is a specific feature you need/like. Read up on it so you know of course what is in store.

1.0 onwards. I've found swapping django versions to be relatively trouble free. At any stage all you need to do is swap symlinks on a source tree on your test server. and of course running that thorough unit test suite you've written will show up any version skew bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade path is not difficult.  I would familiarize yourself with the differences and avoid deprecations, but continue on the battle tested 1.1 branch.  While you should never ever trust software release dates, you also probably don't want to bet your farm on a brand new branch with features you clearly don't need yet.  You've got plenty to do to release in a month.  Upgrade when you have time.  If your release was scheduled for June you might consider it, but for now stick with stability.  That's mho.

Answer (score 1):

Part of our current application under development is being put into production now, but we hope to use Django 1.2 final.  Our strategy is to write code, test and deploy using Django 1.1.1, but also test using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).  There's really no reason not to test your code under 1.2 whatever your deployment decision because you'll want it eventually to be compatible with 1.2.

virtualenv makes the whole process painless and is the key to quickly switching between environments.  It's incredibly easy to set up:

```
easy_install virtualenv
virtualenv django12
cd django12
source bin/activate
```

Then download and install Django 1.2 in the virtual environment and run your tests.  I run the development server in virtualenv on port 8081, so I can have both servers -- using the same application code -- running at the same time, ports 8080, 8081.

In our case we had to remove one import and wrap a few others with try/except conditions.  I had to write a dummy `csrf_token` template tag for CSRF to work -- the Django developers have informed me they'll include a dummy tag in 1.2 final.  We also upgraded the South migrations tool to 0.7-pre, as the current release doesn't support Django 1.2.

Bottom line:  Regardless of your deployment decision, a case can be made for testing both versions of Django if at all possible.